# How to upload a file from rest client in Codeigniter?

Tags: json, codeigniter, rest

I want to upload a file from rest client in codeigniter. How to send a file to rest server from rest client end.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156429/how-do-i-write-a-restful-web-service-that-accepts-a-binary-file-pdf

Comment: how you calling your api get or post method? send data with file attribute.

Comment: @shaiful through post method only i'm calling